# Regular expression replace pattern

Tags: regexp-replace

while googling, I've found this answer for replace pattern to write like this $0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0
and ^.*$ in the find place.
How to sum up the replace pattern, instead of writing so many times. There must be definitely a solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is `$0` in your context? This part `^.*$` matches all chars except a newline, and might also match an empty string.

Comment: $0 captures the 1st group and repeats 50(n)times. This regex copies the captured group and prints/pastes 50(n) times. i.e., the selected string will be multiplied n times.

Comment: If you are using a programming language, you could use a loop.